# EofSensorInputStream best use case scenario

Tags: android, sockets, connection, inputstream

What would be the best scenario and practice of using `EofSensorInputStream` in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EofSensorInputStream` is stream wrapper that triggers actions on `close()` and `EOF`. Primarily used to auto-release an underlying connection when the response body is consumed or no longer needed.

If you are sure about the number of server iterations count and would like to perform some action on connection close like exit application or notify something, this is the best thing to do.

roht